# Dados da mesma tabela para diferentes Views?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net, procedure

Tenho encontrado dificuldade para resolver o seguinte problema:
Supondo que eu tenha a seguinte estrutura no banco de dados:

```
Id              int identity primary key
CodigoBanco     char(3)
Descricao       varchar(100)
Endereco        varchar(300)
Bairro          varchar(100)
CodCidade       int 
Numero          varchar(10)
Complemento     varchar(15)
DataInclusao    datetime
DataAlteracao   datetime
UsrAlteracao    int 
Observacao      varchar(3000)
```

Porém, o sistema possui 3 views:

**View1** - Precisa dos campos Id e Descricao para preencher um dropdownlist;

**View2** - Precisa dos campos Id, CodigoBanco, Descricao, Endereco, Bairro, CodCidade, Numero;

**View3** - Precisa de todos os campos;

Com o Entity Framework, a minha abordagem tem sido retornar um IQueryable do repositório e fazer o Select no Controller de acordo com a necessidade.

Porém isso não é possível quando estamos utilizando Procedure + ADO.NET (Não pela minha vontade).

**Qual seria a melhor abordagem?**

Criar uma procedure e uma classe para cada situação?

Criar uma procedure para cada situação utilizando a mesma classe (mesmo que com o preenchimento parcial das propriedades)?

Desconsiderar o tráfego de dados e sempre trazer todos as colunas, e assim, desenvolvendo apenas uma procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Se o tráfego de dados entre o servidor da aplicação e o banco de dados não for uma questão crítica. O que pode ser feito é a criação de uma `ViewModel` para cada view com o intuito de reduzir o tráfego de dados entre o servidor e o cliente.

Criar uma procedure para cada consulta seria o mais eficiente na economia de recursos e aumento de performance... mas isso vai aumentar a complexidade e gerar mais trabalho na manutenção.

> View1 - Precisa dos campos Id e Descricao para preencher um
>   dropdownlist;

```
public DropDownViewModel
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Descricao {get; set;}
}
```

> View2 - Precisa dos campos Id, CodigoBanco, Descricao, Endereco,
>   Bairro, CodCidade, Numero;

```
public CardViewModel {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string CodigoBanco {get; set;}
   public string Descricao {get; set;}
   public string Endereco {get; set;}
   public string Bairro {get; set;}
   public int CodCidade {get; set;}   
   public string Numero {get; set;}
}
```

> View3 - Precisa de todos os campos;

```
public DetalheViewModel 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string CodigoBanco {get; set;}
   public string Descricao {get; set;}
   public string Endereco {get; set;}
   public string Bairro {get; set;}
   public int CodCidade {get; set;}   
   public string Numero {get; set;}
   public string Complemento  {get; set;} 
   public DateTime DataInclusao {get; set;}
   public DateTime DataAlteracao {get; set;}
   public int UsrAlteracao {get; set;}
   public string Observacao  {get; set;}
}
```